# How to pass in the parameter from one class to another in Java?

Tags: java

Forgive me if this is a duplicated question but I'm a beginner in Java and I'm currently trying to get the parameter value from a class called Name and pass that value into another class called Student.

Name Class:

```
public class Name
{
    public String studentName;


    public Name(String fullName)
    {
        studentName = fullName;
    }
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student
{
    private Name studentName;
    private String id;
    private int credits;
    
    public Student(String studentID)
    {
        studentName = new Name("");
        id = studentID;
        credits = 0;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to get the parameter value of `fullName` which is set in the Name class and pass it in `studentName = new Name("");` for the Student class instead passing in an empty string to retrieve the name.

Comment: Why don't you simpy define `Student`'s constructor as `public Student(String studentID, String fullname)`?

Comment: Adding a parameter in the students constructor wouldn't retrieve the value from the Name class just an empty string would it not?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you don't need `Name` class at all, being it really trivial. Seocondarily you cannot _"retrieve the value from a class"_; you can just retrieve a value from an instance of that class, that is a variable beonging to a specific class. You have `Name` attribute in your Student class, so you'll just need to construct it as well. How? Well... providing a further parameter to Student's constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "taking the parameter value of `fullName`, which is set in Name class"? A class will not have a value, you need access to the instance of this class. I'm pretty sure you will have some kind of control class, e.g. where your `main()` resides.

At some point you will have created a `Name` instance:

`Name n = new Name("Brandon");`

Using this instance of `Name` class, you can access the actual value:

`Student s = new Student("4711", n.studentName);`

, assuming you also have included an additional parameter in your Student constructor:

```
public class Student
{
    private Name studentName;
    private String id;
    private int credits;
    
    public Student(String studentID, String name)
    {
        studentName = new Name(name);
        id = studentID;
        credits = 0;
    }
}
```

, but this would result in you having 2 different `Name` objects.

Another option is to pass the object itself as parameter, so both of your objects reference to same object. Changing `studentName` of either `n.studentName` and `s.studentName` would in theoretically result in the value of the respective other being changed as well (I can recall some discussions regarding that topic in Java though).

```
public class Student
{
    private Name studentName;
    private String id;
    private int credits;
    
    public Student(String studentID, Name nameObject)
    {
        studentName = nameObject;
        id = studentID;
        credits = 0;
    }
}
```

, which is instantiated by

```
Name n = new Name("Brandon");
Student s = new Student("4711", n);
```

You should definitely start reading introductions into object oriented programming, as there are quite a lot of misassumptions just in those few lines of code. The difference between class and object is crucial, also it's usual in those scenarios to have getters/setters rather than public variables in classes. To achieve the kind of dependency you want to have, you might want to look into composition and aggregation in the context of object-orientation. Also the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference is worth looking into.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in such great detail I think I understand what you mean now, I've been doing some reading cooperating classes and the information you have provided has be incredibly useful thank you.